# PHP file upload size limit not working even after changing configuration settings

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration

File with 600 MB is not uploading request is getting crashed even after changing configuration settings in `.htaccess`
`php_value post_max_size 4G
php_value upload_max_filesize 3G
php_value memory_limit 3G
php_value max_execution_time 259200`

this is `php_info()`

```
 Directive                |   Local Value | Master Value
max_execution_time        |      60           60
max_file_uploads          |      20           20
max_input_nesting_level   |      64           64
max_input_time            |      60           60
max_input_vars            |    1000         1000
memory_limit              |      3G         128M
post_max_size             |      4G           8M
```

Can any one help me pls.

Comment: Do you have server permissions? Are you the owner of the server? If not i do not think that you can override some values.

Comment: Yes. I have server permissions the values are set to default and the server is `Nginx`

Comment: you need to change so the master value of memory_limit and post_max_size, have you changed php.ini and apache httpd.conf?